# PHP file size check

Tags: php, filesize

i have this function in funcs.php

```
  function checkfilesize()
    {   global $file;
        global $sizelimit;
//var sizelimit is set as integer using settype()
        if ((isset($file)) && (filesize($file) > $sizelimit)) {
            echo 'File size > '.$sizelimit.'!');
            unlink($file);
            exit;
        } else {
            //
        }
    }
```

upload.php includes this file

When i delete this function from funcs.php all others work fine.

in upload.php i have this

```
<?php require_once 'funcs.php';
            foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $file){
                checkfiletype();
                checkfilesize(); //I tried remove this only but same result. 
            }
            ?>
```

Even HTML is trimmed after this code.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't know what your question is, but don't use globals like this. Pass the file and size limit into `checkfilesize($file, $sizelimit);`

Comment: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'** ...

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the start of the script, or activate error reporting in `php.ini`.

Comment: @Dagon Thanks. This was echo problem. I found. But afer setting error_reporting(-1); php is not shoing me errors about that.

Thank you guys

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have an extra bracket in your code after the '!' mark. Use this.

```
 function checkfilesize()
    {   global $file;
        global $sizelimit;
//var sizelimit is set as integer using settype()
        if ((isset($file)) && (filesize($file) > $sizelimit)) {
            echo 'File size > '.$sizelimit.'!'; //you had an extra ')' here.
            unlink($file);
            exit;
        } else {
            //
        }
    }
```

Comment: If anyone puts a down vote, please explain the reason. Otherwise it provides no help.